# output after using "malloc"

Tags: c

I have written the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *p=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p=0x8F7E1A2B;
     printf("%x\n",*p);

     unsigned char *q=p;

     printf("%x\n",*q++);
     printf("%x\n",*q++);
     printf("%x\n",*q++);
     printf("%x\n",*q++);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the code is as shown below:

```
8F7E1A2B
2B
1A
7E
8F
```

Can anyone please explain the output of this code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please choose either c or c++. They are two different languages. In c++ you wouldnt use `malloc`

Comment: Can you see a pattern? What do you think might be happening?

Comment: Which part did you not understand? The [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the output?

Comment: `malloc` is completely irrelevant; you would see the same if you wrote `int x = 0x8F7E1A2B; int* p = &x; ...`

Comment: given that int's are only required to provide a much smaller range (-32767 to 32767)  your code isn't portable... just saying.

Comment: I was just trying to learn the use of "malloc". How the value of 'p' is stored in the command *p=0x8F7E1A2B; . since *p is of integer type so it will take just 4 bytes, Right ? The pointer variable q is incremented by just one byte, I guess as q is a character pointer.

Comment: Integers are stored in the same way no matter if you allocate them locally or on the heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you would expect to get the bytes in Big Endian order, i.e. `8F-7E-1A-2B`.

That depends entirely on the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your architecture: endianness is the order of bytes in the binary representation of a number. The most common are:

- **Big Endian:** the most significant byte is at the lowest address, followed by the remaining bytes in descending order. i.e. `8F-7E-1A-2B`
- **Little Endian:** the least significant byte is at the lowest address, followed by the remaining bytes in ascending order. i.e. `2B-1A-7E-8F`. Your architecture is little endian
- **Mixed Endian:** all other byte configurations that don't fall under big or little endian are possible, and they fall under the name of mixed endian. i.e. `7E-8F-2B-1A` or `1A-2B-8F-7E`

On a side note, [you shouldn't cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/):

```c
int *p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)); // nope

int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));        // yep
```

Comment: `int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));`...even better, `int *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));`